# How to get list of computers similar to what is shown under "Network" in Windows

Tags: networking, windows, samba

In Windows 7 when I click on *Network* I get a list of computers with the same workgroup of mine. But in Fedora when I click on *Network* I just get a single item *Windows Network* and I can't see the computers that are shown in Windows.

How can I see them in Linux?

Comment: You could `ping` all of the addresses on the network, but I'm not sure why the GUI solution isn't working for you. What version of NetworkManager are you running?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the command line you can use the [`smbtree`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/smbtree) tool:

```
$ smbtree 
Password: 
WORKGROUP
    \\WOLEVER               wolever
        \\WOLEVER\IPC$              IPC Service (wolever)
        \\WOLEVER\Downloads         Downloads
    \\MACBOOK-D397E8        Some MacBook
        \\MACBOOK-D397E8\IPC$               IPC Service (Some MacBook)
        \\MACBOOK-D397E8\Screenshots        Screenshots
    \\MY-HP
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternate solution, although it isn't used in the default File Manager on Fedora, is nmap. Just type e.g.

```
nmap 192.168.0.0/24
```

(`nmap` is just a general-purpose network scanner, not samba-specific.)

Comment: (nmap is just a general-purpose network scanner, not samba-specific.)

Comment: @imz indeed. of course there is more configuration required to set up samba to work on linux anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You might be also interested not specifically in discovering samba (Windows) services on the local network, but in **analoguous** lists of services available on the local network discovered by other protocols.

So here's another answer:

you can also discover the services that have been published through **avahi/bonjour (mdnssd)** with tools like `avahi-browse -a` (CLI) and `avahi-discover` (GUI).

Modern GNU/Linux distros and Mac OS X usually publish itself and their shared services through avahi/bonjour for the discovery in the local network.