# list Windows shared folders (samba) available in the local network?

Tags: networking, samba, services, file-sharing, altlinux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get list of computers similar to what is shown under “Network” in Windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21965/how-to-get-list-of-computers-similar-to-what-is-shown-under-network-in-windows)

I suspect the services shared by Windows (including shared folders) can be looked for with a samba command (similar to `avahi-browse -a` for exploring the avahi/bonjour services available in the local network).

What is this command?

(I want to use it to check that the folders shared by Windows can really be seen in the network. Then I'll think how to use the shared files in my GNU/Linux system running on a laptop; perhaps, mount them or use them by exploring them in Nautilus or a similar browser (although I do not usually use such graphical browsers; I'm inclined to command-line and Emacs' `eshell` and `dired`).)

Comment: Actually, my situation is very similar to the one described in <http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21965/how-to-get-list-of-computers-on-network>, and the accepted answer there (`smbtree`) should work for me, too.

Comment: But neither `smbtree --no-pass` nor `smbtree --no-pass --broadcast` sees the Windows shared folders in my LAN. Perhaps, my router settings are not OK (although I'm able to ping the Windows host in question), or the Windows sharing setup is not OK...

Answer (score 1):

`smb4k` can do that, but it's a graphical software.